# How to extract filesystem name only without /

Tags: regex, perl

For following Sample data and program provided below , please help me to find correct regex .

```
#cat df.dat
/root                      
/dev/data1                 
/dev/data1/data3
/usr/local/oravg/oradat
```

what pattern to use to extract root, data1, data3 and oradat without "/"

$ perl grepperl.pl -pattern=' ' df.dat

```
$ cat grepperl.pl
#! /usr/bin/perl -s -wnl
BEGIN {
# -pattern='RE' switch is required
$pattern or
warn "Usage: $0 -pattern='RE' [ file1 ... ]\n" and
exit 255;
}
/$pattern/ and print;
```

Comment: You can use this `(? <=/) \w+$`

Comment: If you're manipulating paths, you should use a path manipulation module, not a regex. Pick one: [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny), [Path::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class), [File::Spec](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Spec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this negation basedregex in MULTILINE mode:

```
/[^\/]+$/m
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nL3hU9/1)

`[^\/]+$` will match 1 or more of any char that is not `/` before line end.

Answer (score 5):

Perl:

```
use File::Basename qw( basename );

my $fn = basename($qfn);
```

bash:

```
fn="$( basename "$qfn" )"
```

bash (pipeline):

```
... | xargs -n 1 basename | ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple bash way (although bash is not tagged in the question)

```
$ cat test 
/root                      
/dev/data1                 
/dev/data1/data3
/usr/local/oravg/oradat

$ while read line; do echo ${line##*/}; done < test 
root
data1
data3
oradat
```

Refer [Bash Substring Removal](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Guess this would be more self explanatory:

```
use File::Basename;

my @paths = qw (/root                      
                /dev/data1                 
                /dev/data1/data3
                /usr/local/oravg/oradat);   

for my $path (@paths) {
    my $dirname  = dirname ($path);
    my $filename = basename ($path);
    print "$path:\n\tFile: $filename\n\tDirectory: $dirname\n\n";
}

1;
```

Result:

```
/root:
        File: root
        Directory: /

/dev/data1:
        File: data1
        Directory: /dev

/dev/data1/data3:
        File: data3
        Directory: /dev/data1

/usr/local/oravg/oradat:
        File: oradat
        Directory: /usr/local/oravg
```

Answer (score 0):

Just anchor you selection to the end of the line and disallow any slash character `/`.

```
[^/]*$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gC1wW6/1)